# Simple Set Operation with Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Consider $X(\omega) \ge -1$ be a discrete random variable and define an event
>   $$
> \{\omega: 1+a X(\omega) \le \varepsilon\}
> $$
>   where $a \in [0,1]$ and $\varepsilon \in [0,1]$.
>   I was wondering can I use the hypothesis that $X \ge -1$ to conclude the following inclusion relationship 
>   $$
>  \{\omega: 1 + a \cdot (-1) \le \varepsilon\} \subset  \{\omega: 1+aX(\omega) \le \varepsilon\} ?
> $$

I think *not* because the left-hand-side has no more random variable there but not sure about this.

Thank you.

Comment: The left-hand side is either $\Omega$ or $\varnothing$ depending on whether $1-a\leq \varepsilon$ or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inclusion relationship does not hold and counterexample is quite simple.

The first set $\{ \omega: 1+ a \cdot (-1) \leq \epsilon \}$ only implies that $a \geq 1 - \epsilon$.

For counterexample: Consider e.g. $X(\omega) = 10$, $a =1$ and $\epsilon = 0.1$. Then you see that inequality $1 + aX(\omega) \leq \epsilon$ does not hold and thus the inclusion is violated.